# Nested For Loops Giving Incorrect Output

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to get the following output from my code:

```
x  o  o  o  o  
x  x  o  o  o  
x  x  x  o  o  
x  x  x  x  o  
x  x  x  x  x
```

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            System.out.print(" x ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" o ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But I'm not able to get the correct output. I'm getting the following output using this code:

```
 x  o  o  o  o 
 o  x  o  o  o 
 o  o  x  o  o 
 o  o  o  x  o 
 o  o  o  o  x
```

Comment: What data structure are you using to store that? ever thought about just writing a 2 dimensional array, then printing it?

Comment: what does you code output and what are you missing in comparison top the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the condition `i == j` you will only get the `x` in the diagonal elements. If you want the desired output then you'll have to modify the condition to `i >= j` instead.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (i >= j) {
            System.out.print(" x ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" o ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

```
 x  o  o  o  o 
 x  x  o  o  o 
 x  x  x  o  o 
 x  x  x  x  o 
 x  x  x  x  x
```

Comment: omg Thank you very much , it worked perfectly , thank you again

Comment: @Remmargrop Your Welcome! If this solved your problem then please accept the answer by clicking the grayed out tick below the voting counter.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `if(i == j)` to `if(j <= i)` and everything will work!

**Long explanation:**

Think about the logic

- `i` is the outer loop, take charge of each row
- `j` is the inner loop, print each character(`x` and `o`) with-in the line
- So how much x should be print (i.e. value of `j`), depending on the line number (i.e. `i`)
- Printing x from the first position (`j == 1`), to the `i` position (`j == i`), that is, `j` from `1` to `i`, which write in Java is **`j <= i`**